# working with file system through python

Tags: python, windows, filesystems

I want to write a program in python which detects the type of file system and then makes some changes to master file table (in NTFS) or File allocation table (in FAT).

Is there an explicit way to do this ? With which lib? I am a beginner by python.
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure you'll find a library to do exactly what you want here.

Comment: You are trying to do something a beginner should not be doing. So gain some experience before doing something like that for instance be able to follow http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364993(v=vs.85).aspx . You need to dig winapi to do that.

Comment: I did not want a library to do this exactly, I just want it to help me to write a program in this way. I have tried PyWin32, sys,..
I have tried winapi too, But I did not know so much about them. I want an explicit example, If it is possible :)

Comment: What kind of changes? Are you sure it is necessary to touch those tables directly?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I fully understand the question, but I would recommend maybe embedding you python code in C++ and using the Boost libs, http://www.boost.org/doc/libs that would be my first point of call, good luck.

Comment: thanks for your answer, But I should write the program by python. However I can write the C++ code and call it from python.
Is it possible to expalin more an give me an example?

Comment: What is it exactly you are looking to achieve? from my use of this, I've been able to get paths and manipulate them using boost, then PyRun_SimpleString python scripts, if you were to access file systems using boost, you could then pass them into a python function as parameters and manipulate them from there? but I've only scratched the surface of using boost, you would probably have to do some research to get what you need.